# Windows 10 Black screen after moutherboard logo,no cursor,no safe mode

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot

I had windows 7 and upgraded via windows update to windows 10.Everything ran smoothly but i deleted my windows 7 recovery backup to free up space.The next time i turned on my pc i get to moutherboard logo and bios options and after that a black screen and fans runing fast,no cursor,no keyboard,only when i press ctr+alt+del my pc restarts.Can't enter safe mode.So i booted usb flash drive with ubuntu and boot repair program in hope it can somehow fix my windows 10 boot.Did not help.Can any of you give me any suggestion on how to fix my windows 10 via ubuntu flash drive? Or can someone give a link to download an .iso file with windows 10 recovery disk or repair disk? Im 99% sure its not a hardware problem.I ran Asus In-Rom Diagnostics on my hardware and passed all tests.Also i can access my windows 10 folder via ubuntu.Any suggestion is well apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First I would make sure you have the most recent version of your motherboard's BIOS installed. Windows 10 gave me trouble with a GPU until I updated my BIOS.

It could be that your hard drives MBR (Master Boot Record) has been corrupted. If you have an option to reset the MBR try that.

Finally, it all else fails, there is always a clean install. If you completely upgraded to Windows 10 and had it running, you can do a straight clean install of Windows 10. Upgrades do not have a license key, so when the installer asks for the Windows 10 key, look at the bottom left for the small writing and select, "Enter this later". Once the install is done, Windows should activate itself by comparing your computer's hash with the hash on file. The license key that you can view with a "key explorer" is a generic number and NOT a real license key.

Warning.... If you change too many hardware components from what you had when you upgraded, Windows will not activate and you will have to contact Microsoft Support. Different pieces of hardware have different values, so you might get away with swapping out a single hard drive (if the one you have is failing), but changing a motherboard is a reason for Windows not to activate. On one computer, after I upgraded to 10 and had it running, I changed several drives, my NIC, and the GPU, and on the next boot Windows 10 was no longer activated. Had to call Microsoft Support.

You can download the iso for any version of Windows at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench

Good luck!!